Looping intersect_ray() bounces in 3D
How to create laser bounces loop using intersect ray? I'm using Godot 4.2 GDscript 3D intersect_ray().
My code so far, I couldn't wrap my head around writing the looping part.
Thanks
    var max_reflections :int = 10
    var cast_length = 100
    
    var from : Vector3
    var to : Vector3
    var query : PhysicsRayQueryParameters3D
    var result : Dictionary
    
    ### FIRST CAST
    from = marker3d.global_position
    to = marker3d.to_global(Vector3(0,0,-cast_length))
    query = PhysicsRayQueryParameters3D.create(from, to)
    result = space_state.intersect_ray(query)
    
    if result:
        line(from, result["position"], Color(1, 0, 0), 1) ### 1ST LINE
    else:
        line(from, to, Color(1, 0, 0), 1)
    if !result:
        return

    ### SECOND CAST
    var result_position = result["position"]
    var result_normal = result["normal"]
    var shooting_direction = result_position - from
    var target_direction = shooting_direction.bounce(result_normal)
    line(result_position, result_position + target_direction * cast_length, Color(1, 0, 0), 1) ### 2ND LINE
    
    for i in range(1, max_reflections):
        ##### SECOND CAST
        from = result.position
        to = result.position + target_direction.normalized() * cast_length
        query = PhysicsRayQueryParameters3D.create(from, to)
        result = space_state.intersect_ray(query) ### SECOND COLLSIION
        if result:
            _ball(result) # Placing a visible mesh ball for debugging
        else:
            line(from, to, Color(1, 0, 0), 1)
        if !result:
            line(from, to, Color(1, 0, 0), 1)
            return

        i += 1
        if i >= max_reflections:
            break

I got the initial shooting to bounce. I then tried to cast another at the end of initial bounce to the next bounce and make it loop.
End result should be a reflecting (bounce) laser in 3D
